# Nginx only serves images, but not css or js, Rails 3.1

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails-3.1, assets

Here's my conf for the website on Rails 3.1:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.mysite.com www.test.mysite.com;
    root /var/www/mysite/test/current/public;

    location ~* ^/assets/ {
            expires max;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
            break;
    }

    passenger_enabled on;


    error_page  404  /404.html;
    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /500.html;

    client_max_body_size 10M;

    if (-f $document_root/maintenance.html) {
            rewrite  ^(.*)$  /maintenance.html break;
    }

}
```

Only images are rendered though. css and js show 404 page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you have set the correct permissions on your CSS, JavaScript files ?

Comment: Yes, I checked it, READ for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I haven't payed enough attention. Those css and js files were not actually compiled for some reason and, thus, have not appeared in `assets/public` dir. At least not all of them: for instance `application.css` is there, but other css files are not. Anyway, that is not an nginx problem, so I'm marking this as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to share with you my [configuration on Github](https://gist.github.com/711913) of nginx+passenger in production mode. it resolves you problem with server static content right way

Comment: Thanks. Good stuff in there. However, I looked through it carefully and I haven't found what is the problem with my configuration. The only relevant block about static assets is basically the same as mine. To be sure I copypasted it, but still no luck. What am I not seeing?

Comment: where your css/js are located? can you copy-paste nginx error.log please?

Comment: and check the permissions for the directories, to ensure that nginx can serve them as well. Rails3 turned off the assets serve by default, so nginx probably has some issues with access to static content

Comment: css/js are in `/var/www/mysite/test/current/public/assets`

error.log contains nothing related to the problem. The last entry is `unknown directive "gzip_static" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test.mysite.com:8` (don't know why it's not supported, but I removed it anyway). I visited the page, then checked error.log - nothing new appeared in it. Permissions are set to "READ for all" on files and "EXECUTE for all" on dirs.

Comment: if "gzip_static" is in the configs, it's looking gzipped files only.

Comment: try this out: gzip -c -n -3 all.css > all.css.gz and the same with all.js

Comment: don't forget to reconfigure nginx with --with-http_gzip_static_module

Comment: Thanks, good tips, although I've found what the problem was. Posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, one of my stylesheets was not being compiled, but this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) provided me with a solution.

I added my `custom.css` to `config/environments/production.rb` this way...

`config.assets.precompile += ['custom.css']`

After that I issued `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and my problem was solved.